# In QTP, can we only use shared object repository and disable local repository?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp

I just started to use QTP to test a java monitor we have. I think it will be cleaner that if put all the objects in shared repository and do not use local repository at all. Is there any down side that of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

**No. Well, it depends.**

There is no reason to disable the local repo. **There is not even a way to do that!** But yes, you can simply avoid *using* it.

I usually have a rule active in the team that reads "whatever is in the local repo should be gone upon check-in". I even have a check in the library initialization code that looks if there is stuff in the local repository and yields a warning if so.

But it depends on the AUT if this is useful, and on your workflow:

The repo that a test is actually using is the combination of the associated (shared, central) repository, "overlaid" by what is in the local repo. **So you can not only add, but also modify the shared repo entries by using the local one.** This is a quite powerful feature which allows you to define the "norm" case in the shared, and the exceptional cases in the local repository. 
If you AUT has well-defined GUI objects which are easily re-identify-able in various contexts, fine. But if not, this feature comes handy.

I agree that this "overlaying" mechanism easily leads to "bugs" (or let´s say: playback problems) that are hard to track down. Usually, as Murphy suggests, the local repo is the last idea that comes to mind when you are diagnosing strange playback symptoms.

It is, however, quite some clickwork to open the central repo through the object repo manager, check it out, make it writeable, etc. for every small change. **So the local repo is a good "buffer" for updates.**

Consequently, especially if you are using QC as a central storage point, and possibly have enabled version control there, you will *love* the ability to add new stuff into the local repo first and move them over to the central repo in one load just before checking in the change. (By the way, other team members would kill you if you´d checkout the central repo file for more than 5 minutes, effectively putting a write-lock upon it.)